# Apache / Ubuntu blocks routing

Tags: apache, symfony, ubuntu, routes, vhosts

got a mysterious problem on symfony routing.

I am switching to symfony with me developement setup, cause I had always problems to get things running on windows with linux vm ...

All right, LINUX runs but my symfony routes are not working.

Talking about this piece of code:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/index", name="index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'IndexController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

In Apache it says

```
Not Found
The requested URL /test was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) Server at tools.dev Port 80
```

If I change the route to @Route("/", name="index") everything works fine. But any other route than root is not possible. And it is not a symfony problem. If I start the php internal server and try the Url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/index) in browser it works fine.

```
Permissions are set to 
n00n@ubuntu:/var/www/html/n00n-tools$ ls -la
insgesamt 296
drwxrwxr-x 13 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:20 .
drwxrwxr-x  3 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:16 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:17 assets
drwxrwxr-x  2 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:17 bin
-rwxrwxr-x  1 n00n n00n   2036 Jul  7 16:22 composer.json
-rwxrwxr-x  1 n00n n00n 208091 Jul  7 16:22 composer.lock
drwxrwxr-x  4 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:17 config
-rwxrwxr-x  1 n00n n00n   1231 Jul  7 16:17 .env
-rwxrwxr-x  1 n00n n00n   1231 Jul  7 16:17 .env.dist
-rwxrwxr-x  1 n00n n00n    416 Jul  7 16:17 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  3 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:28 .idea
-rwxrwxr-x  1 n00n n00n    302 Jul  7 16:17 package.json
-rwxrwxr-x  1 n00n n00n   1116 Jul  7 16:17 phpunit.xml.dist
drwxrwxr-x  2 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:17 public
drwxrwxr-x  6 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:17 src
-rwxrwxr-x  1 n00n n00n   9881 Jul  7 16:22 symfony.lock
drwxrwxr-x  3 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:19 templates
drwxrwxr-x  2 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:17 tests
drwxrwxr-x  2 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:17 translations
drwxrwxr-x  4 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:17 var
drwxrwxr-x 20 n00n n00n   4096 Jul  7 16:22 vendor
-rwxrwxr-x  1 n00n n00n    852 Jul  7 16:17 webpack.config.js
```

This is my apache config file for the host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName n00n.tools
        ServerAlias n00n.tools
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/n00n-tools/public/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html/n00n-tools/public/>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any hint for me?

Thx, Regards, 
n00n

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? Also, I always put the Directory block outside the VHost, but I'm not sure whether it is important. mod_rewrite is likely the issue.

Comment: yes, it was enabled. This was my first thing to check.

Comment: Can you then paste the `.htaccess` file that should do the rewriting to your PHP entrypoint?

Comment: @TobiasK I never used a .htaccess file for it. I always activated modrewrite by a2enmod rewrite. Am I wrong?

Comment: You need `mod_rewrite` enabled, `a2enmod` works for that. But you also need to actually use it to rewrite everything to your `index.php`. Basic example:     `RewriteEngine On`
    `# Handle Front Controller...`
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
    `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Comment: Symfony docs state there is a package for that, I never tried that though: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules - anyways, whether you install the package or add the file manually, there have to be `RewriteRule`s in `.htaccess` or the webserver config for routing to work with Apache.